# Flutter - A screen is grey in release build, but works fine when run from Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter

**This is the [link](https://github.com/paulpoyyayil/quik_shoppe/blob/master/lib/screens/cart.dart) to the dart file**

Whenever i run this from android studio the app works fine, but when i build apk and run from there it displays blank screen.

[How its supposed to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sOpJ.jpg)

[How it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrVRo.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same issue. The app worked perfectly fine in debug mode but some widgets were having some issues and were showing in grey color in the release build.

The solution is that you remove Expanded widgets which are wrapped on Column:

```
                      Expanded(
                        flex: 5,
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "Peramangalam House",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 24,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: kTextColor),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Methottuthazham, Kozhikode",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: kTextLightColor),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
```

To just:

````
                         Column(
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                              child: Container(
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Text(
                                        "Peramangalam House",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 24,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: kTextColor),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        "Methottuthazham, Kozhikode",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: kTextLightColor),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),```
````

Answer (score 0):

This happens because some widget is not rendering correctly.

Check the application log while in android studio and what error is being related.